# Redis on CentOS 8

Tags: redis, centos8

I want to install **redis 5.0.7** in **CentOS 8** but **5.0.3** is the only avaliable rpm.
Is it safe to install from source?

Comment: What does "safe" mean?

Comment: Have you considered Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trust the source provider -- e.g. you downloaded from one of redis' servers -- then you should be fine.

Their site shows they also provide hashes for integrity: https://redis.io/download#how-to-verify-files-for-integrity

But, it also states the hashes don't match for the 'generic redis-stable.tar.gz tarball'

Comment: p.s. Here is the link for 5.0.7: https://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.7.tar.gz